# VB Net Textbox compare Value Lower to Highest and Change Color

Tags: vb.net

I have the following Textboxes (A1-A2-A3 to A8) (B1-B2-B3 -... A-8) (C1-C2-C3 ....- A8) for each letter, if you can not make the code for all the letters.
That is, to calculate for each letter the values of the A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 ... a8 textboxes, B1 with b2, b3 , b4 .... b8) and so on. and then change the color of the textbox by value, the smallest to the largest/biggest.
 I want to change the color of each one according to value, between the smallest and the biggest, I have such a code but I have no idea why it does not work and I do not know for sure if the code is written correctly. I am currently using Visual Basic 2008 (VB-2008), so my project is working in VB 2008.

Such a code can help guide you how this can work, because this code works perfectly no matter how many Textboxes I create and how many letters it calculates me perfectly. Because each Textbox contains a number from 1 to 7, it calculates each Textbox by column, and tells me the final calculated value of those Textboxes. But now I need for the final calculated value to change my color by the smallest to the largest textbox.

```
Private Sub txtDrawSum()
    On Error Resume Next
    For y = 1 To 8
        Dim sum = 0
        For x = 1 To 15
            Dim tbName = "txtDraw" & Chr(64 + x) & y
            sum += CInt(TabControl3.TabPages(0).Controls(tbName).Text)
        Next
        TabControl3.TabPages(0).Controls("SumDraw" & (0 + y)).Text = sum.ToString()
    Next
End Sub
```

This is the code that should do what I want, unfortunately I do not know why it does not work and what is the cause.
This code must be changed based on my text box, which starts with SumtxtDraw. (A1..A8, B1....B8, C1....C8-etc)

This code should compare the values of the textboxes, and each textbox should be given a specific color depending on whether it is the smallest or the largest.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     FillColorList()
 End Sub

Private Sub ColorTextBoxes()
    FillTextBoxList(16, 23)
    Dim SortedList As List(Of TextBox) = SortList()
    Dim index As Integer
    For Each txt As TextBox In SortedList
         txt.BackColor = lstColor(index)
         index += 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FillColorList()
    lstColor.Add(Color.Red) 'for lowest number
    lstColor.Add(Color.BlanchedAlmond)
    lstColor.Add(Color.PaleGreen)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Chartreuse)
    lstColor.Add(Color.CadetBlue)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Orange)
    lstColor.Add(Color.DarkMagenta)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Violet) 'for highest number
End Sub

Private Sub FillTextBoxList(StartNumber As Integer, EndNumber As Integer)
    lstTextBox.Clear()
    For suffix = StartNumber To EndNumber
        lstTextBox.Add(DirectCast(Controls("TextBox" & suffix.ToString), TextBox))
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SortList() As List(Of TextBox)
    Dim orderedList = From txt In lstTextBox Order By CInt(txt.Text) Descending Select txt '$"{scorer.Score} - {scorer.Name}"
    Dim SortedList As List(Of TextBox) = orderedList.ToList
    Return SortedList
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ColorTextBoxes()
End Sub
```

Comment: How many of you are working on this code? This code was posted as an answer to a question by @Angga Sillvert. Is this a homework assignment? The correction that was posted as an edit to the question is add at the Class level (Form level) `Private lstColor As New List(Of Color)` and 
 `Private lstTextBox As New List(Of TextBox)`

Comment: @Lucian Dorin is posting the same code in his questions. What is going on.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921449/compare-value-multiple-textbox-vb-net/53925520#53925520